# ElasticSearch query_string fails to parse query with some characters

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, pyelasticsearch

I'm using the ElasticSearch (2.4) and the official Python client to perform simple queries. My code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es_client = Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")
index = "indexName"
doc_type = "docType"

def search(query, search_size):
    body = {
        "fields": ["title"],
        "size": search_size,
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "fields": ["file.content"],
                "query": query
            }
        }
    }
    response = es_client.search(index=index, doc_type=doc_type, body=body)
    return response["hits"]["hits"]

search("python", 10) # Works fine.
```

The problem is when my query contains unbalanced parenthesis or brackets. For example with `search("python {programming", 10)` ES throws:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'Failed to parse query [python {programming}]')
```

Is that the expected behavior of ES? Doesn't it use a tokenizer to remove all those characters?

Note: This happens to me using Java too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was reading the documentation and the `query_string` is more strict. The following are reserved characters: `+ - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`

So, like jhilden said, I would have to escape them or use `simple_query_string` instead.

Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Answer (score 11):

I know I am late enough but I am posting here and I hope it'll help others. As we know from the Elasticsearch documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters)  ES has some reserved characters.

The reserved characters are: `+ - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`

So, now you've two possible solutions to fix it. These are working perfectly for me when I encountered special character issue

**Solution 1:** Wrap your special characters with `\\`

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "country_code.keyword": "IT"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "display",
            "query": "Magomadas \\(OR\\), Italy"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**Solution 2:** Use `simple_query_string` with no change on your `query` but it doesn't support `default_field`, so you can use `fields` instead.

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "country_code.keyword": "IT"
          }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "fields": ["display"], 
            "query": "Magomadas (OR), Italy"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in prev answers, some characters need to be *escaped*;

```
+ - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /
```

> `"query": "my:name*&&"` should be `"query": "my\\:name\\*\\&&"`

---

## Regex to the rescue ✨

With the help of a simple regex, we can easily escape these characters

#### Python

```py
import re

def escape_elasticsearch_query(query):
    return re.sub('(\+|\-|\=|&&|\|\||\>|\<|\!|\(|\)|\{|\}|\[|\]|\^|"|~|\*|\?|\:|\\|\/)', '\\\\\\1', query)


query = 'my:name*&&'
escaped_query = escape_elasticsearch_query(query)
print(escaped_query)
```

output:

```
my\:name\*\&&
```

#### Javascript

```js
function escapeElasticsearchQuery(query) {
    return query.replace(/(\+|\-|\=|&&|\|\||\>|\<|\!|\(|\)|\{|\}|\[|\]|\^|"|~|\*|\?|\:|\\|\/)/g, '\\$&');
}


let query = 'my:name*&&';
let escapedQuery = escapeElasticsearchQuery(query);
console.log(escapedQuery);
```

output:

```
my\:name\*\&&
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex. I think I found a slight bug, though. I needed to add an addition backslash to get backslashes properly escaped (only did this in Python):
`re.sub('(\+|\-|\=|&&|\|\||\>|\<|\!|\(|\)|\{|\}|\[|\]|\^|"|~|\*|\?|\:|\\\|\/)', '\\\\\\1', query)`

Answer (score 2):

When using `query_string` in ES it's a bit weird.  You need to escape it with a double backslash.

## The following fails:

```
GET index1/job/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["jobNumber"],
      "query": "827950 { foo"
    }
  }
}
```

## The following works

```
GET index1/job/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["jobNumber"],
      "query": "827950 \\{ foo"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: if you were using a terms query or something else like that you would *not* need to escape that `{`

Answer (score 0):

As to the current Elasticsearch version (8.10) there is an undocumented flag "escape" which escapes the query string for you (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/77604)

So you can write this type of request without escaping special symbols yourself:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "escape": true,
          "query": "elf bar/eb design",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```